# linking altair axis to slider

Tags: python, jupyter, altair

I am using altair inside a Jupyter notebook. Can altair link a slider to anything besides a chart itself? For example, if I have an axis that I want to bin, I can make that interactive via ipywidgets:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

@widgets.interact
def example(my_bins=widgets.IntSlider(min=10,max=600,value=50)):
    stuff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,2),columns=["x", "y"])
    my_x = alt.X("x:Q").bin(maxbins=my_bins)
    my_y = alt.Y("y:Q").aggregate("mean")
    c = alt.Chart(stuff).mark_line().encode(x=my_x, y=my_y)
    c.display()
```

But could I also do that directly using a binding_range, for example? If I wrap the binding_range in a param, I can pass it to a chart, but I have no idea how to link the slider value to the maxbins parameter of alt.X.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the new [JupyterChart functionality](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/jupyter_chart.html) in Altair 5.1+ to achieve this. After you set up your chart, you would do something like

```
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, link
slider = IntSlider(23, min=0, max=100)
link((slider, "value"), (jchart.params, "cutoff"))
slider
```

As in [this section.](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/jupyter_chart.html#linking-variable-params)

Comment: I had been staring at those examples for quite a while, but I still do not get how to apply them here: If I do it like this:
`
bins = alt.param(name="bins", value=5)
stuff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,2),columns=["x", "y"])
my_x = alt.X("x:Q").bin(maxbins=bins)
my_y = alt.Y("y:Q").aggregate("mean")
c = alt.Chart(stuff).mark_line().encode(x=my_x, y=my_y).add_params(bins)
jchart = alt.JupyterChart(c)
jchart
` 
I get the error that '{'expr': 'bins'}' is an invalid value for `maxbins`. Valid values are of type 'number'.

Comment: @Keiichi I believe your code is correct and the issue is that Vega-Lite does not yet support using expressions for the maxbins parameter. I believe it is this PR https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7463 or maybe this one https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7445 that would add this functionality in Vega-Lite.

Comment: oh I see, thank you!